# Quiero hacer un div que de ancho siempre sea el 100% de la pantalla pero que adentro pueda conteneralgo que sea mas ancho que la pantalla misma en px

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, frontend

Tengo unn problema haciendo un proyecto de front, tengo que hacer una pagina responsive y necesito hacer un "row" ( en mi caso estoy usando bootstrap5 ) el cual contenga 5 divs u objetos los cuales tienen que tener un numero minimo de pixeles digamos 210px de ancho y de alto un minimo de 210 igual digamos que suman 1050px en total o 1100 si les damos espacios entre ello, lo que me gustaria hacer es algo como lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si se dan cuenta el div que engloba a los otros divs siempre se ajustan al ancho  de la pantalla pero los de adentro solo se salen de la pantalla sin mas, el problema que estoy encontrando es que no logro hacerlo, por que lo que hice es bloquear el scroll horizontal pero si visualizo desde otro dispositivo la pantalla se carga mal por que la imagen no es responsive, no se si me di a entender lo que quiero es un div que siempre se ajuste al 100% del ancho de la pantalla y tenga vario divs de tamano definido pero al momento de reducir la pantalla esta solo muestre lo que entre del div como la imagen de arriba.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta imagen es la del error como los divs no se redimensionan me es imposible que se visualice bien

Comment: Si no muestras el código es difícil ayudarte. Yo creo que con un ejemplo y una explicación breve se entiende mejor.

Comment: entonces los recuadros interiores no se apilan, sino que simplemente dejan de verse?

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas un container con ancho máximo (en tu caso, `max-width: 100vw` ocupará toda la pantalla) y `overflow` distinto a `visible`. (en mi ejemplo usé `overflow:hidden`.

Dentro de éste habrá un contenedor interior con `display:flex` y `flex-wrap:nowrap` para forzar a que los cuadritos se mantegan en una sola fila.

Los cuadritos mismos no tienen ningún atributo en particular en que debas reparar. Sólo les dí margen y padding para que se entendiera dónde va cada uno. En total puse 9 cuadritos y debieran verse sólo 4 en pantalla.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 225px;
  border: 1px solid ccc;
  display: flex;
}

.interior {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.cuadrito {
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: 3px solid #6A9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="interior">
    <div class="cuadrito">1</div>
    <div class="cuadrito">2</div>
    <div class="cuadrito">3</div>
    <div class="cuadrito">4</div>
    <div class="cuadrito">5</div>
    <div class="cuadrito">6</div>
    <div class="cuadrito">7</div>
    <div class="cuadrito">8</div>
    <div class="cuadrito">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```